# jQuery chaining css properties with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, chain

I have the following **jQuery** problem.

First I  use `height: auto;` for my `.container` element  so that a scrollbar is added if the `.container` content is bigger than the browsers *window height*. After 2 seconds the *height* should get the *window height*.

This is my current code in the `$(document).ready(...)` function:

```
$('.container').css('height', 'auto' ).delay(2000).css('height', $(window).height());
```

Currently the `css('height', $(window).height())` doesn't get applied at all.

What is wrong with my jQuery chain?

Comment: @Ben Fortune: The jQuery `css()` function does not need it. It assumes `px`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`css` is immediate and not queued/delayable (like `animate` is).

Your options are use `setTimeout` or add them to the animation queue (or use methods that *are* queued).

e.g. using timer

```
   $('.container').css('height', 'auto' );
   setTimeout(function(){
        $('.container').css('height', $(window).height());
   }, 2000);
```

**JSFiddle:** (thanks to @Raghu Chandra) http://jsfiddle.net/zd5xweb6/

using a queue:

```
   $('.container').css('height', 'auto' ).delay(2000).queue(function(){
        $(this).css('height', $(window).height());
   });
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/zd5xweb6/1/

Comment: When i wanted to answer your (Same) answer was already here!! my fiddle goes here http://jsfiddle.net/raghuchandrasorab/zd5xweb6/

Comment: @Raghu Chandra: have used your JSFiddle, with credit. Thanks :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks especially for the queued version. Works like a charm! Note: could you add a semicolon after `...$(window).height)` for perfect valid js

Comment: @pbaldauf: Glad it helped. I usually do add semi-colons after every statement, and I'll correct it, but on a single statement, inside a function scope, it is certainly optional. :)